# Multiprocessing and sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, file-descriptor

I am trying to make multiprocessing and socket programming work together, but, I am stuck at this point. Problem is that, I am getting this error:

```
  File "multiprocesssockserv.py", line 11, in worker
    clientsocket = socket.fromfd(clientfileno, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Complete code that causing the error is as following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging
import socket

logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.WARN)

def worker(queue):
    while True:
        clientfileno = queue.get()
        print clientfileno
        clientsocket = socket.fromfd(clientfileno, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        clientsocket.recv()
        clientsocket.send("Hello World")
        clientsocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_workers = 5
    socket_queue = mp.Queue()
    workers = [mp.Process(target=worker, args=(socket_queue,)) for i in
            range(num_workers)]

    for p in workers:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('',9090))
    serversocket.listen(5)
    while True:
        client, address = serversocket.accept()
        socket_queue.put(client.fileno())
```

edit: I am using socket.fromfd because I can't put sockets into a queue :) I need a way to access same sockets from different processes somehow. That is the core of my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that :) platform is Linux.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After working on this for a while, I decided to approach this problem from a different angle, and following method seems to be working for me.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging
import socket
import time

logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)

def worker(socket):
    while True:
        client, address = socket.accept()
        logger.debug("{u} connected".format(u=address))
        client.send("OK")
        client.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_workers = 5

    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('',9090))
    serversocket.listen(5)

    workers = [mp.Process(target=worker, args=(serversocket,)) for i in
            range(num_workers)]

    for p in workers:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(10)
        except:
            break
```

Comment: This seems like a clever solution. Did you experience any problems with having several listeners to the same serversocket?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert so I can't give the real explanation but if you want to use queues, you need to reduce the handle and then recreate it:

in your **main** :

```
client, address = serversocket.accept()
client_handle = multiprocessing.reduction.reduce_handle(client.fileno())
socket_queue.put(client_handle)
```

and in your worker:

```
clientHandle = queue.get()
file_descriptor = multiprocessing.reduction.rebuild_handle(client_handle)
clientsocket = socket.fromfd(file_descriptor, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

also

```
import multiprocessing.reduction
```

That will work with your original code.
However, I am currently having problems with closing sockets in worker processes after they were created as I described.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code on what's mentioned above - https://gist.github.com/sunilmallya/4662837 multiprocessing.reduction socket server with parent processing passing connections to client after accepting connections